# FatalErrorException Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: docker, nginx, rabbitmq, php-7.2, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to run my symfony 3.3 project in the docker. It's working fine out of docker. All containers are running: nginx:alpine, php-fpm 7.2, PostgreSQL, rabbitMQ.

I'm receiving this error:

```
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

in AnalyzeServiceReferencesPass.php (line 71)
at AnalyzeServiceReferencesPass->processValue()
in AnalyzeServiceReferencesPass.php (line 118)
```

dev.log

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Error: Maximum
>   execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" at
>   /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php line 710
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 0):
>   Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded at
>   /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php:710)"}

Answer (score 1):

Its means that your request is very slowly, so you need to increase your max_execution time
`max_execution_time = 900` or `ini_set('max_execution_time', 900);`
or change driver of request
also check if you have a infinite cycles

Comment: I did set this in php.ini file via `- ./docker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini` but nothing has changed.

Comment: Add a volumes: section to your php service in the docker-compose.yml file, map a local directory with a custom.ini file to /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d, and restart your container. Whatever valid settings in that file will override those from the main php.ini file.

This works in my own project:

`php:
  volumes:
   - ./localpath/custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini`

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I did. But I moved to Dockerfile as `RUN echo "max_execution_time=900" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini` and it works ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

`RUN echo "max_execution_time=900" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini` line added to Docker file made it work.